# What files or folders should I add to make a setup file from my code in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I have a C# code and I want to make a setup file for windows. I have used "Setup and development" section of visual studio. This is the picture of the process:

[image: Picture of setup trend]

My question is about "Application files" section in the picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5jcJ.jpg). Exactly, what files and folders of my C# project (by what formats) should be added to program works correctly?

Thank you

Comment: Depends.  Everything in your EXE project's bin\Release folder except the vshost.exe file should be the 95% case. If you have any additional assets that need to be copied then you'll find out quickly enough when you test your installer.